# How to make a discord.js bot dm a message to a specific person?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a bot and i want to make it so if you send a specific message to the bot in dms it will send a specific user a dm that says that this command has been run

This is what i have:

```
if (message.content == "the message here") {
   if(message.guild === null) {
   message.channel.send("the response here");
} else { 
   return;
  }
}
```

i want it so after running the command it sends a dm to me saying that it has been run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Discord.js v12 you can use this:

```
client.users.fetch("some user id", false).then((user) => {
   user.send("some message");
});
```

So if you enter your own discord user id into the above snippet, whenever a command has been run it will send you a message.

Comment: Why would they want to fetch themselves? They're already accessible through `message.author` and `message.member`

Comment: I assume he wants to send a message to himself. Not back to the author. Also i dont see the point in your answer then.

Comment: Shucks,  misunderstood the question on the first read through.

Comment: dont worry, happens ;)